# Xcode 6 Framework Target Tutorial

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, xcode6

Is there a walkthrough/tutorial explaining how to create a Framework target with Xcode 6.x?

The immediate problem I'm dealing with is that the consumer of my framework (my test harness) gets a compiler error of "myFramework.h file not found" when it tries to "#import ". But in the left-hand panel of the test app project you can see the framework and can see the header file when you drill down into the "Headers" folder of the framework.

So how can the header file be there but the application can't see it?  My "framework search paths" variable is blank in the test project.

After getting past this issue, I'm curious as to what all I need to include in the framework's "Headers" and "Copy Bundle Resources" sections.  Because my framework has a ton of dependencies on other libraries, does it need to put all those header files into the framework target as well?

Finally, I'm curious if all architectures are getting linked into the framework binary.  I've set "Build Active Architectures Only" to "No" for my framework project. Does that automatically ensure all architectures are built & copied into the Framework target?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

See [generator-swift-framework](https://github.com/cybertk/generator-swift-framework), it's used to create a Xcode Embedded Framework project from a Template Project.